# MailGun - Exact API call to get count of deliverd messages between start and end date

Tags: mailgun

Can someone help me what is the right mailgun API call to get the count of delivered messages between custom start and end date.

I have been trying with this but getting empty result:

**curl.exe --user "api:key-XXXX" -G https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.com/stats/total -d event="delivered" -d start-date="Mon, 16 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT"**

The maingun API documentation is here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-stats.html

MailGun support team is repeatedly pointing to the documentation but nobody is ready to provide me the workable API call. It is also surprising to see that MainGun administrative portal don't facilitate users to see number of emails sent between a range of dates!!! Anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old one, but I'd like to answer for future reference.

> MailGun support team is repeatedly pointing to the documentation but
>   nobody is ready to provide me the workable API call.

They are correct - everything is in docs. In your particular case you are passing data with `-d` parameter, but you should use `--data-urlencode` instead (as shown in their API examples). Correct call:

`curl --user "api:key-XXXX" -G https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.com/stats/total --data-urlencode event="delivered" --data-urlencode start-date="Mon, 16 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT"`

Also, you might consider use `start` parameter instead of legacy `start-date` (recommended in their documentation).

> It is also surprising to see that MainGun administrative portal don't facilitate users to see number of emails sent between a range of dates!!! Anyway...

At the moment of writing this answer, there is a [Reporting](https://mailgun.com/app/reporting/overview) tab that shows detailed stats for each type of event. It also allows you to select desired date range and filter results.

Comment: Thanks @zeulus for your time and consideration, Back in June 2016, My official ticket with MailGun needed several weeks to get answer from their dev team!! MailGun very recently added UI to check this info in admin panel.